# Pure spark vs spark SQL for quering data on HDFS

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have (tabular) data on a hdfs cluster and need to do some slightly complex querying on it. I expect to  face the same situation many times in the future, with other data. And so, question:

*What are the factors to take into account to choose where to use (pure) Spark and where to use Spark-SQL when implementing such task?*

Here is the selection factors I could think of:

1. **Familiarity with language**: 
   In my case, I am more of a data-analyst than a DB guy, so this would lead me to use spark: I am more comfortable to think of how to (efficiently) implement data selection in Java/Scala than in SQL. This however depends mostly on the query.
2. **Serialization**: 
   I think that one can run Spark-SQL query without sending home-made-jar+dep to the spark worker (?). But then, returned data are raw and should be converted locally.
3. **Efficiency**: 
   I have no idea what differences there are between the two.

I know this question might be too general for SO, but maybe not. So, could anyone with more knowledge provides some insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About point 3, depending on your input-format, the way in which the data is scanned can be different when you use a pure-Spark vs Spark SQL. For example if your input format has multiple columns, but you need only few of them, it's possible to skip the retrieval using Spark SQL, whereas this is a bit trickier to achieve in pure Spark.

On top of that Spark SQL has a query optimizer, when using DataFrame or a query statement, the resulting query will go through the optimizer such that it will be executed more efficiently.

Spark SQL does not exclude Spark; combined usage is probably for the best results.

Comment: Interesting point about Spark-SQL optimization. I feel like I understand what cluster communications and computations are induced by pure spark code. But I don't know much about what spark SQL does, nor how.

Comment: Good point about Spark not excluding Spark-SQL. This is not what I meant to imply and I slightly rephrased my question.

Comment: In the end Spark SQL generates a Spark job based on your query to be executed on the Spark cluster. 
There are some introductory slides regarding the new DataFrame API here: http://www.slideshare.net/databricks/introducing-dataframes-in-spark-for-large-scale-data-science

Comment: I running on spark 1.1.1 (not my cluster), so no DataFrame :-(

Comment: You should consider voting for a newer version, as there have been quite some fixes and optimizations in 1.2+. Also the API around ETL in DataFrame in 1.3 is much nicer than SchemaRDD in 1.2 (and earlier).

Comment: I'll talk to the cluster admin, hopefully it's simple enough for them